# trocar logo ao diminuir largura da tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

gostaria que quando o site fosse visto em celulares a logo aparecesse menor, tenho duas logos, logo1(maior) e logo2(menor), como faço pra que quando o site seja aberto em um aparelho com tela até 800px de largura a logo1 seja trocada apela logo2

logo1

```
<img  id="minhaImagem" src="img/logo1.png" Alt="logo">
```

.

.
...código jquery...

.

.

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar

Comment: Já tentou com media query? max-width acho que resolve.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

  if (window.screen.width < 800) { 

    $('#minhaImagem').attr('src','img/logo2.png');

  }

});
```

Só com `CSS` você consegue também. Mas com `jquery` pode fazer assim.

Answer (score 1):

Use as Media Queries do CSS para alterar a visualização/disposição dos elementos dependendo do tamanho da tela.

Quando uma media query é verdadeira, a camada de estilo ou as regras de estilos correspondentes são aplicadas. [Mais informações em MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries)

Para o seu caso, crie uma `div` com a classe `logo`, no css informe o background com a imagem logo. Ex.:

HTML:

`<div class="logo"></div>`

CSS:

```
<style>

/* Regra geral */
.logo {
    background-image: url("img/logo1.png");
}

/* Regra aplicada quando a largura da tela estiver entre 0px e 800px */
@media (max-width: 800px) 
{
  .logo{
    background-image: url("img/logo2.png");
  }
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**MEDIA QUERY**

O método para trabalhar com larguras de tela e responsividade é o [CSS Media Query](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/), e pode ser aplicado da seguinte forma:

```css
img {
  transition: 0.52s all;
  padding: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img#minhaImagem2 {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Fiz com 500px para poder testar, mas é só trocar para 800px */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  img#minhaImagem2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 25px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  img#minhaImagem {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img  id="minhaImagem" src="img/logo1.png" Alt="logo">
<img  id="minhaImagem2" src="img/logo1.png" Alt="logo 2">
```